# What is wrong with my tax calculator program?

Tags: python

```
def taxcalc (tax):

    income = float(raw_input('Welcome to the PAYG Tax calculator,please enter your gross income, and your net income will be displayed.\n'))

    if income <= 18200:
        print income

    elif income >= 18201 and income <= 37000:
        beforetax1 = income * 0.19
        tax = income - beforetax1

    elif income >= 37001 and income <= 80000:
        beforetax2 = income - 3572
        secondtax = beforetax2 * 0.325
        tax = income - secondtax

    elif income >= 80001 and income <= 180000:
        beforetax3 = income - 17547
        thirdtax = beforetax3 * 0.37
        tax = income - thirdtax

    elif income >= 180001:
        beforetax4 = income - 54547
        fourthtax = beforetax4 * 0.45
        tax = income - fourthtax

print 'Your net pay is $',tax

print 'The amount of tax paid is $',beforetax
```

It does not print anything except for tax.

(EDIT)

```
def taxcalc ():

    income = decimal.Decimal(raw_input('Welcome to the PAYG Tax calculator, please enter your gross income, and your net income will be displayed.\n'))

    if income <= 18200:
        net = income

    elif income > 18200 and income <= 37000:
        tax = income * 0.19
        net = income - tax

    elif income > 37000 and income <= 80000:
        tax = income - 3572
        tax = tax * 0.325
        net = income - tax

    elif income > 80000 and income <= 180000:
        tax = income - 17547
        tax = tax * 0.37
        net = income - tax

    elif income > 180000:
        tax = income - 54547
        tax = tax * 0.45
        net = income - tax

    print "Your net income is $",net

taxcalc()
```

Comment: Why are you passing `tax` as an argument to the function, when the point of the function is to _calculate_ `tax`? Also, why isn't it `return`ing the value it calculate? Also, why does `<= 18200` just print the income instead of calculating anything?

Comment: Because when `income <= 18200` there is no tax.

Comment: Also, using `<= 18200` and `>= 18201` on floats means that if someone makes `$18200.50`, he's not in any tax bracket. (Plus, in most countries, tax brackets are marginal—if you make $200000, you don't pay 45% on all $200000, you pay 0% on the first $18200, 19% on the everything from there to $37000, etc.)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: So, that means it should leave `tax` as an undefined variable instead of setting it to 0?

Comment: One last thing: it's a bit misleading to call your net pay your `tax` and your tax your `beforetax`. Make the variables mean what they claim to mean and it'll be a lot easier to spot errors in your code.

Comment: I was just suggesting a reason for no calculation being done when `income <= 18200`. The function's flow is another matter.

Comment: Another problem: `beforetax` is referenced only in the `print` statement and never assigned. Needs more C for MCVE.

Comment: @abarnert because in Australia, anything less then 18200 does not get taxed.

Comment: Scope. Indent your `print` statements at the bottom as part of your function.

Comment: @ScottMiller: Yes, and? That means that the program should never assign anything to `tax` so you eventually raise an `UnboundLocalError` exception or `NameError` instead of assigning `tax = 0`? Is there a law in Australia that people who make less than $18200 are a logic error and programs should not try to deal with their existence?

Comment: @abarnert ok well can you please suggest a fix to it? I'm extremely new to python.

Comment: I'd recommend the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), particularly the section on functions. It'll give you a better understanding of what should go where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a whole slew of problems here, and you have to fix all of them, including at least the following:

- Your `taxcalc` function sometimes `print`s a value, sometimes calculates some temporary values and then forgets them and does nothing; the one thing it never does is actually `return` its values to the caller, e.g., `return tax, beforetax1`.
- Your `taxcalc` function takes a `tax` parameter that it doesn't use. It shouldn't.
- You define a `taxcalc` function, but never *call* it anywhere, so it isn't doing any good. You need something like `tax, beforetax = taxcalc()`.
- Your variable names are misleading. You have something named `tax` which is the net pay rather than the tax, and something named `beforetax` which is the amount of tax paid rather than the before-tax income. Similarly, `beforetax1` is actually the tax, not the before-tax income, while `beforetax2` is the before-tax income, `secondtax` is the tax, and `tax` is the after-tax income.
- Your `elif` bounds all have gaps. For example, if someone makes `$18200.50`, that's not `<= 18200`, nor is it `>= 18201`. You don't actually need the lower half of each test; just do `elif income <= 37000` (if it was `<= 18200`, it would already have been handled in the `if`, so it won't get to this test).
- Your first case, for people under the minimum taxable income, needs to do the same thing as the others: calculate and return a tax cost and a before-tax income (in this case, that's just `return 0, income`). You can't just do *nothing*, or you're going to get some kind of exception somewhere when someone wants those values and they don't exist. Also, just printing the income doesn't do anything useful.

---

There are also things that aren't actually broken, but should be improved:

- It's probably better to move the `raw_input` *outside* the function, then pass the income in as a parameter.
- There's no reason to name a variable `beforetax2` in one block and `beforetax3` in another. If they both mean the same thing, and there's no way they're going to get in each other's way, just call them both `beforetax`.
- You probably want to round to even cents—or maybe use `decimal.Decimal` instead of `float` (see the moneyd` recipes in the docs).<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* I don't know about Australia, but in the US, if the IRS screws up and sends you a tax bill for $17.3811713, you're in big trouble. Pay $17.38, and that's underpaying and they'll issue penalties; pay $17.39 without explicitly specifying that you're overpaying and they'll return your check uncashed and then fine you for not paying on time. Call them and they'll tell you it's not a problem, and then three months later they've garnished your wages for $288 for not paying that 0.11713 cents, and they tell you "the information we give you isn't actually guaranteed to be correct, and doesn't count legally as advise".</sub>

Comment: Thanks alot, I've changed and fixed what I think your saying and what I understand. Any more help would be appreciated. Please check the question.